# SCSS: How to place an On-Screen-Keyboard on bottom of screen?

Tags: css, sass, on-screen-keyboard

I have an on-screen-keyboard. I want to place it on bottom of screen So that 
when we click a TextEdit, the keyboard appears in button of screen. *The button of current frame is my purpose.* 
I have the following code but it doesn't work.

```
.ui-keyboard {
    border-radius: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 80%;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: We need more information about the HTML where this CSS applies and maybe also the  CSS of the surrounding elements of the `.ui-keyboard` element. Use [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: your css is right . Can you share on button click code

Comment: I program in Aurelia and the code is not a normal HTML code. It is not helpful to write here. If the code is correct, I have to find the other reasons.

Comment: Can you take the picture of what is happening with this code. Because maybe you need to change the `position` to `fixed`.

Comment: @Maverick I did it.

Comment: @Sohrab From the picture I can't see if this is your whole viewport. But if it is it's look kinda ok.. To check color the `.ui-keyboard` for example red, and see where the borders are. Maybe the `.ui-keyboard` is at the bottom and the keys (buttons) are pushed from the bottom of it.

Comment: @Maverick I checked it. just TextEditor is effected and changed the colour. I will change the above picture to see the result (yellow colour).

Comment: @Sohrab Hmm you see something is off.. Your whole `div` is collapsed. If buttons are floating you need to "clear" them. Search for a term "css clearfix" and add it to keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
top: auto;
bottom: 16rem;
position: fixed;
```